# Coredata: Not casting Coredata Fetch Results to Objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am doing a map app and I am caught on an issue.

I can't seem to get Coredata to convert results into the relevant Pin data.

Here is the method I am using to download the Pins from CD

```
    func fetchAllPins() -> [Pin] {
    let error: NSErrorPointer = nil

    // Create the Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Pin")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    // Execute the Fetch Request
    let results = sharedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: error)

    // Check for Errors
    if error != nil {
        println("Error in fetchAllEvents(): \(error)")
    }
    println("RESULTS ARE")
    println(results) // Gives results ( see console below)

    return results as! [Pin] // Returns Blank no idea why

}
```

Here is the output from the Console showing the data is being returned.

```
   Optional([<Pin: 0x7fb9144dcf60> (entity: Pin; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://5E886C33-FB0F-4035-9362-489A0BBFB0D9/Pin/p1> ; data: {
    lat = "54.98870385960889";
    long = "-2.732679843506143";
    reference = 1;
}), <Pin: 0x7fb911697ee0> (entity: Pin; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://5E886C33-FB0F-4035-9362-489A0BBFB0D9/Pin/p2> ; data: {
    lat = "54.58505971892202";
    long = "-1.719484882196165";
    reference = 1;
})])
```

Here is the Pin Object that I am using:

```
    import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreData

@objc(Pin)

class Pin : NSManagedObject {
    struct Keys {
        static let lat = "lat"
        static let long = "long"
    }
    @NSManaged var lat:Double
    @NSManaged var long: Double
    @NSManaged var reference: NSNumber




 override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
        println("-----")

        println(entity)
    }

init(llat: CLLocationDegrees, llong: CLLocationDegrees, llinksToImages: [String]?, context: NSManagedObjectContext) {

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Pin", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
    super.init(entity: entity,insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    lat = llat as Double
    long = llong as Double
    reference = 1

}
```

Any advice would be really welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to crack it.. Would be lovely to understand why my solution up there didn't work but in case someone needs it:

If you replace:

```
return results as! [Pin]
```

and instead push it into a its own unpacked results array it seems to play nice. 
eg :

```
var myAwesomeResults = [Pin]()
for pinItem in results{
myAwesomeResults.append(pinItem)
}
return myAwesomeResults // returns data correctly!
```